# Webrtc: RecordRTC splitting issue observed only on iOS when recording from laptop-side

Tags: javascript

I'm experiencing a splitting issue with recorded video in a WebRTC-based application, where the recording is performed on the web application side using RecordRTC (JavaScript).The problem arises after saving the recording to the storage and playing it back in a media player. This problem arises exclusively on iOS devices when initiating the recording from the web application running on a laptop. Interestingly, the recording functionality works seamlessly on Android devices.

```
    var remoteStreamToBeRecorded = evt.stream;
var options;


// Check and set the options for RecordRTC
if (canRecord('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"')) {
    options = { mimeType: 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' };
} else if (canRecord('video/webm; codecs="vp9, opus"')) {
    options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs="vp9, opus"' };
} else {
    console.error('RecordRTC is not supported or the MIME type is not supported');
    alert('RecordRTC is not supported by this browser.');
    return;
}
remoteRecorder = RecordRTC(remoteStreamToBeRecorded, {
        type: 'video', mimeType: 'video/webm', recorderType: MediaStreamRecorder, disableLogs: true, timeSlice: 1000, checkForInactiveTracks: false, onTimeStamp: function (timestamp) { }, bitsPerSecond: 128000, audioBitsPerSecond: 128000, videoBitsPerSecond: 128000, frameInterval: 90, previewStream: function (stream) { }, video: HTMLVideoElement, canvas: {
            width: 640,
            height: 480
        }, sampleRate: 96000, desiredSampRate: 16000, bufferSize: 16384, numberOfAudioChannels: 2, frameRate: 30, bitrate: 128000 });`enter code here`
remoteRecorder.ondataavailable = videoDataHandler1;
 if (remoteRecorder) {
    remoteRecorder.startRecording();
} else {
    console.error('Remote recorder is not properly initialized');
}
function videoDataHandler1(blob) {
debugger;
console.log('Inside videoDataHandler');
console.log('Event:', blob); // Log the event object

//if (event.data && event.data.size > 0)
if (blob && blob.size > 0) {
    SecondCounter = SecondCounter + 5;
    console.log('video blob received');
    recordedBlobs.push(blob);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    console.log('Created FileReader:', reader); // Log the created FileReader object
    //reader.readAsDataURL(event.data);
    const blob1 = new Blob(recordedBlobs, { type: 'video/mp4' });
    const fileName = `video_${window.videoCounter}.mp4`;
    saveVideoToFile(blob1, fileName);



    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    console.log('Started reading data with FileReader');
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log('Inside reader.onload');
        console.log('e:', e); // Log the event object inside onload

        if (window.videoCounter > 0) {
            saveVideoByteArraytoCloudNew(reader.result.toString(), window.videoCounter, WebReferenceNumber, surveyType);

            
                endCall();
            }
        }
    };



    window.videoCounter++;
}
```

}
Note:I was not able to find the error where it is occuring
Could someone provide insights or suggestions on troubleshooting steps or potential solutions to address this issue specifically on iOS devices in a WebRTC context?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is "the issue"? The only thing you say about it is "splitting". What does that mean?

Comment: Hi deceze thank you for response .  Issue is after recording the video stream  and save it in storage if play a video is coming with 2 tiles playing same video in the  both tiles

Comment: This is a case where a screenshot would be acceptable and necessary.

Comment: i've added the screenshot now . Please check.